# AWS disksize degradation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops, devops-services

i have 1 ami which was created from instance with m4 large and 1000GB disk space. Now by using ami i have sponge the instance which by default has m4 large and 1000 GB disk

but we are thinking for downgrading the sponge instance to t2 medium and 200 GB is it possible.

THe first part of it that is bringing it to t2 medium is done but we are stuck at the disk size down-gradation

Comment: What's [tag:devops] in here?

Answer (score 1):

AWS doesn't provide a way to do this directly, but it is possible with some effort.  This page outlines the process: https://cloudacademy.com/blog/amazon-ebs-shink-volume/

Essentially, you mount a smaller volume of the desired size to the same system and copy the files (or mirror a smaller partition), then you switch to using the smaller volume.

The exact process you use for doing that will vary depending on what operating system you're using, as well as whether or not the volume you're attempting to shrink is bootable.